# Can't sort Excel PivotTable Row Label as Numbers

Tags: excel, sorting, pivot-table, powerpivot

Using PowerPivot and creating a PivotTable in Excel 2010, trying to sort a Row Label column that contains numerical values as numbers instead of as text. No matter what I've tried, though, Excel refuses to play along.

For example, I created a very simple Excel spreadsheet with a single column called "MyValues" that looks like so:

```
**MyValues**
  1
  2
  3
  4
  12
  12
  23
  44
  12292
```

I've imported that spreadsheet into another file using PowerPivot and, in both that source spreadsheet and in the PowerPivot window, have confirmed that a) the data type is numeric and b) that the values sort as expected (i.e. from largest to smallest or vice versa).

But when I create a PivotTable off that and use that MyValues column as a Row Label, Excel instead sorts the values as though they were text:

```
**MyValues**
  1
  12
  12292
  2
  23
  3
  4
  44
```

Am I missing something, or can you only sort numbers as numbers when they're in Values column?

Comment: I have the same problem in Excel 2010, but only while using PowerPivot based PivotTables. Regular PivotTables seem to sort fine. Did you ever find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

It's tedious, but you could drag them into place.

Comment: Yeah, the amount of data in this one makes that unscalable. Looks like it works as I'd hoped in 2013, though. Upgrading...

Answer (score 0):

Seems the behavior is fixed in Excel 2013.